# Unit Testing overloaded methods C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I want to write a common unit test case on two overloaded methods I'll be asserting the same conditions.  I want to avoid writing a unit test for each overload. What would be the best approach?

```
   public void method(Type1 t) {
      \\ Do something on t
       privateMethod()
   }

   public void method(Type2 t) {
      \\ Do something on t
       privateMethod()
   }

   private void privateMethod()
       ...execute common operations
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "best"?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? What do you want to assert on?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(/* Input parameters for method1 */)]
[InlineData(/* Input parameters for method2 */)]
public void TestMethod(/* input parameters */)
{
  // Call the method (method1 or method2)
}
```

Comment: (Edited original question) both methods have the same name as they are overloads.